# How to fix a IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: pyqgis, indexerror

I'm still working on my script for vineyards. I need to count row and vine in row.
So I code this :

```
#Nombre de rang
nbr = QgsExpression( "ID LIKE '%-1'" )
itnbr = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( nbr ) )
litnbr = list(itnbr)

print 'nombre de rang : ' + str(len(litnbr))

#Nombre de pied dans le rang
for i in range(len(litnbr)):
    rang = str(i+1)
    print 'rang : '+ rang
    itp = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("ID LIKE '{0}-%'".format(rang[i])))
    litp = list(itp)
    print 'nombre de pieds dans le rang ' + rang + ' : ' + str(len(litp))
```

I runned it and it works for first loop, first part of second loop and then it crash :

```
nombre de rang : 60
rang : 1
nombre de pieds dans le rang 1 : 6
rang : 2

exec((script), ns)
          File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
        IndexError: string index out of range
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rang` contains a single value, but you later use it as if it was an array.
The line

```
 itp = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("ID LIKE '{0}-%'".format(rang[i])))
```

should be changed to

```
 itp = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("ID LIKE '{0}-%'".format(rang))
```

(if your `ID = rang`, else use `i`)

Let's note that it works in the 1st iteration as the 1st element of a single value is valid (`rang[0]==rang`)